# Angular - Dynamic header

Tags: angular5, angular-routing, angular-services, angular4-router

I have a [website](https://dinetodaydevweb.azurewebsites.net/) currently under development.

**Issue**: When accessing a page, the front page is briefly displayed - and then the current page is shown.

[image]

Please try refreshing this [link](https://dinetodaydevweb.azurewebsites.net/good-morning-cafe) to have better understanding. Notice that while loading, the front page is displayed - and after load completes, then the correct page is displayed.

**Question** What shall I do to avoid the front page being shown during refresh of a page?

**Background**: Every page in the [website](https://dinetodaydevweb.azurewebsites.net/) have different header. My approach:

- Created header helper service
- Header helper service keep watching for route change
- Depending on current route it sets different css class on header component template. This works perfect if user navigates through website without refreshing page
- Please see html and header helper service code below

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'no-hero': headerType === 400, 'restaurant-page': headerType === 200, 'restaurant-list': headerType === 300}"
    class="top-section">
  <div class="top-section-bg">
  </div>
 // Code removed for brevity
</div>
```

```js
private setHeaderType(): void {
  if (this.currentUrl.includes("search-restaurants")) {
    this.headerType = HeaderType.restaurantSearch;
  } else if (this.currentUrl.includes("profile") || this.currentUrl.includes('faqs') || this.currentUrl.includes('bookings')) {
    this.headerType = HeaderType.noHero;
  } else if (this.currentUrl === "/") {
    this.headerType = HeaderType.home;
  } else {
    this.headerType = HeaderType.restaurantDetail;
  }
  this.headerTypeSource.next(this.headerType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution here is to have some styles in the index.html as plaintext, hardcoded styles, that hide the front page on reload. Aka.

index.html

```
<html>
    <style>
    .loading-overlay {
        z-index: 99;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: red;
    }

    .loading-overlay--hide { display: none; }
    </style>

    <div class="loading-overlay"></div>
</html>
```

And when angular boots, I just do this to hide the loader

```
document.getElementById('full-page-loader').className += " full-page-loader--hide";
```